# Does the android support Unicode natively?

Tags: android

Does the android support Unicode natively?
But in String.xml we have to edit it with UTF-8 ??
Any way to check the string's encoding? unicode or utf-8 ?....

Comment: Please clarify how string.xml is related to native code in your case..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android does support Unicode.

Since you seem to be confused about the relationship between UTF-8 and Unicode, I recommend that you save yourself a lot of pain and just read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean UTF-16 or UTF-8 - Android works with UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Android supports Unicode characters in UTF-8 encoding - but lacks proper fonts and a complex text rendering system do display many scripts and languages properly.